# instantiate a class with different input

Tags: java, oop

I have a question, now i have two classes as following

```
public class mainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String st1="st1";
        String st2= "st2";

        System.out.println(st1);
        System.out.println(st2);
        testClass t1=new testClass(st1);
        testClass t2=new testClass(st2);
        System.out.println(t1.getString());
        System.out.println(t2.getString());
    }

}
public class testClass {
    static String testString1;
        public testClass(String a ) {
            testString1=a;
        }
        public String getString(){
            return testString1;
        }
}
```

---

### output

```
st1
st2
st2
st2
```

shouldn't output be the following?

```
st1
st2
st1
st2
```

since I created two instances of testClass, each has different input, why am i getting same output??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `testString1` variable in `testClass` is declared static, so it will hold the same value across all instances of `testClass`.

If you want `testString1` to hold a unique value for each instance of testClass that gets created, then you need to remove the static declaration.

Comment: No problem.  A second pair of eyes always helps... :-)  Can you accept an answer so that your question is marked as answered?

Answer (score 0):

`testString1` is [static](http://www.javacamp.org/javaI/Modifier.html) (`static String testString1;`) so it is shared between all instances of the class.

Answer (score 0):

`static String testString1;` should be `String testString1;`.  By declaring it `static` you have associated the single `String` instance (named `testClass.testString1`) with all instances of `testClass`.

Answer (score 0):

No because the static keyword.
Static means that the string will be the same for all instances of this class. Remove it and it will work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

The output is like that for static variable. You have to understand static to understand your output.

static variable is the variable is the variable which share all the instance of the object. You can access it without creating an instance. If you change it from one instance then object will find the change.

When you create instance **t1**, static String **testString1** initializing with **st1**. But the next line you create instance **t2**, and **testString1** initialize with **st2**. **t1** and **t2** are actually refer the same variable. So when you print **t1.getString()** it gets the update value of **testString1**.